Jaeger Operator Installation on EKS
I have deployed jaeger operator using helm chart on EKS-
https://github.com/jaegertracing/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jaeger-operator
Operator is installed, but when i create jaeger agent as CR, it does not gets created.
Kubernetes version - 1.29
Helm - 3
Jaeger operator - latest i.e 1.57
Is something missing? Does jaeger operator not supporting k8s 1.29?

Not really an answer, since you haven't given enough context about the problem. Can you please specify the following:

Check the logs of the jaeger-operator pod for errors
Verify the CRD you defined, you should include your configurations here
Also, kubectl describe jaeger <CR-NAME>
Does your EKS cluster have the resources needed to run this?
Helm chart may have config issues, please share the config here

You can also ask on the CNCF Slack or open an issue on our repo.
